# How to sort an Array of Tuples using sorted? (Cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type)

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, swift3

I am trying to sort an array of tuples using `sorted`.

The error I get is:

> Cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type (((MyClass1, MyClass2)) -> Bool)

The array is created like this:

```
class MyClass1 {
    var id: Int
    init(id:Int) { self.id = id }
}

class MyClass2 {
    var id2: Int
    init(id2:Int) { self.id2 = id2 }
}
let array1 = [MyClass1(id:4), MyClass1(id:3), MyClass1(id:2), MyClass1(id:1)]
let array2 = [MyClass2(id2:1), MyClass2(id2:2), MyClass2(id2:3), MyClass2(id2:4)]
var tuples = zip(array1, array2)
```

What I have tried:

```
tuples = tuples.sorted { (left, right) -> Bool in
    return left.1.id2 > right.1.id2
}

tuples = tuples.sorted { $0.1.id2 > $1.1.id2 }

tuples = tuples.sorted(by: { (first: (MyClass1, MyClass2), second: (MyClass1, MyClass2)) -> Bool in
    return first.1.id2 > second.1.id2
})
```

The expected output is(pseudo, handwritten):

```
[(myClass1WithId_1, myClass2WithId2_4),(myClass1WithId_2, myClass2WithId2_3),(myClass1WithId_3, myClass2WithId2_2),(myClass1WithId_4, myClass2WithId2_1)]
```

The tuples sorted by myClass2.id2 descending.

---

**Update**

I found out how to workaround the issue. The error seems to be wrong/misleading.

I can sort it when assigning the result to a new variable:

```
let tuples2 = tuples.sorted { (left, right) -> Bool in
    return left.1.id2 > right.1.id2
}
```

while assigning it to the existing variable gives me the mentioned error:

```
tuples = tuples.sorted { (left, right) -> Bool in
    return left.1.id2 > right.1.id2
}
```

Comment: Well it depends on how you want to sort your data. Can you provide an example input and expected output?

Comment: Updated question with expected output.

Comment: Quite interesting. Good detective work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to sort an array of tuples

But problem is that your `tuples` is *not* an array. (It is a thing called a Zip2Sequence.) The solution is to coerce it to an array:

```
var tuples = Array(zip(array1, array2))
```

Now your original code will work:

```
let array1 = [MyClass1(id:4), MyClass1(id:3), MyClass1(id:2), MyClass1(id:1)]
let array2 = [MyClass2(id2:1), MyClass2(id2:2), MyClass2(id2:3), MyClass2(id2:4)]
var tuples = Array(zip(array1, array2)) // *
tuples = tuples.sorted { (left, right) -> Bool in
    return left.1.id2 > right.1.id2
}
```

The reason *your* solution worked is that a sorted sequence yields an array. So you can't reassign the array to the sequence variable (`tuples`) but you can assign it to a different variable (`tuples2`). My solution *starts* with an array, so the resulting sorted array *can* be assigned back to the same variable.

Comment: Nice finding. I have to check out `Zip2Sequence` to find out why the hell it does not return an array. Thx!

Comment: Well, the usual thing to do next is `for...in`, so a sequence is all you need. And the sequence is _lazy_ so there is no work to be done until you actually do `for...in`. A sequence is not a collection (but a collection is a sequence, and an Array is both). You can't sort a sequence.

Comment: You can most certainly sort a sequence.

Comment: @shallowThought `zip(_:_:)` doesn't return an `Array` because there's almost no reason to justify it. It returns `Zip2Sequence`, which is a struct that wraps 2 iterators (of the 2 sequences you gave it), which iterates them in sync. Converting it to an array would be slower, since `n` element have to be iterated, and memory wasting, since `2n` elements have to be redundantly copied (where `n` is the length of the shorter of the 2 sequences). You can sort type conforming to `Sequence`, including `Zip2Sequence`.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov You can sort a sequence but not in place. He was trying to reassign the sorted sequence back to the Zip2Sequence variable. That was the issue. The sorted sequence is an array, so he couldn't assign it back to the Zip2Sequence. My answer starts with an array, which can be assigned back to the array variable after sorting.

Comment: @shallowThought Sorry, I was talking to Alexander.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov If you look at the docs, you'll see this key sentence: "Returns: A sorted array of the sequence’s elements". So you didn't sort the sequence; you made a new thing, an array.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: Thanks. Very interesting, wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to use `sorted()` because the tuple type `(MyClass1, MyClass2)` does not conform to `Comparable`, so the sorter would not know how to sort your tuples. You can't add an extension that adds conformance to it either, because tuples can't have extensions or conform to protocols.

You can however, use `sorted(by:)`, which requires you give a closure which defines the sorting between elements.

```
class MyClass1 {
    var id: Int
    init(id:Int) { self.id = id }
}

class MyClass2 {
    var id2: Int
    init(id2:Int) { self.id2 = id2 }
}
let array1 = [MyClass1(id:4), MyClass1(id:3), MyClass1(id:2), MyClass1(id:1)]
let array2 = [MyClass2(id2:1), MyClass2(id2:2), MyClass2(id2:3), MyClass2(id2:4)]
let tuples = zip(array1, array2)

let sortedTuples = tuples.sorted{ $0.1.id2 > $1.1.id2 }

print(sortedTuples)
```